# Django with Vue, detect form validation error

Tags: django, forms, validation, vue.js

I have a Django ModelForm which is displayed in the template by using using crispy forms. After the user fills out the fields and presses a Submit button, an email is sent at the backend using Django's core send_email.

The problem is that the call to send_email is synchronous, so the user has to wait for the next page to load (success/failure page) but in this time the user might press the Submit button again and this generates multiple POSTs, making multiple emails.

I want to use Vue.js to make the button inactive once the user presses it but only if it passes Django's form validation. Is there a way to detect this?

Comment: If you're using Vue, wouldn't it make more sense for the backend to use an API of some sort rather than generating the form? That way you can generate the form in your view code, use DRF (or similar) to generate your API, which will send the errors back to you for display, and will only send the email if everything is valid.

Comment: @TomCarrick The intention was to slowly move form Django to Vue on the frontend since I'm very new to Vue. Now I have decided to just do what you mentioned and made a DRF endpoint and the rest is much of what Redha answered from the Javascript point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your button :disabled="!readyToSend" where readyToSend can be returned by your data function or a computed propoerty.

Before submitting the form set this variable to false, afater receiving data from your API, reset it to true.

In the following example I've choosen to make readyToSend a computed proporty where it will return true if the form is valid and if the process is not waiting for the API response.

The complete [Code Pen example is here](https://codepen.io/redhax/pen/KKdyzdE)

html file :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
      <form @submit.prevent>
        <input type="text" v-model="dataToSend" placeholder="Something to send">
        <button type="button" :disabled="!readyToSend" @click="send">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function(){
      return {
       message: "please enter your message and click on send.",
        dataToSend: "",
        sentAndWaiting: false,
      }
  },
  methods:{
    send: async function(){
      this.sentAndWaiting = true;
      // Send Data Here
      this.message = "sending....";
      try{
        let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
        let jsonResponse = await response.json();
      }
      catch(e){
        this.message = e.message;
      }
      // reponse received ... do Something with it
      this.reponseReceived();
    },
    reponseReceived: function(){
      this.sentAndWaiting = false; 
      this.message = "Ok. Got The response.";
    }
  },
  computed:{
    readyToSend: function(){
      return this.dataToSend.length > 0 && !this.sentAndWaiting;
    }
  },

});
```

in my browser I had to test this by going to the developper tools and limit my internet connexion to the GPRS and disabling cache:

[Screenshot DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXHCP.png)